# javax.validation get field field owner object

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation

Imagine the current situation:

```
class Alpha
{
    Integer x1;
    @BiggerThan("x1")
    Integer x2;
}
```

I want to write a custom constraint validator for this `@BiggerThan` annotation.
However, there doesn't appear to be a way to get hold of the `Alpha` instance in the `ConstraintValidator` implementation. The signature of the isValid method is

```
public boolean isValid(Integer value, ConstraintValidatorContext context)
```

There is no 'Object owner' parameter. There doesn't seem to be a way to get it through the `context` either.

Is it at all possible to implement this in the javax.validator framework?

I'm using hibernate-validator as implementation, but I'm open to changing that. I would consider a hacked solution tied to a particular jsr303 implementation if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it as a class-level constraint:

```
@BiggerThen(a = "x1", b = "x2")
class Alpha {
    Integer x1;
    Integer x2;
}
```

For example, as [here](http://git.springsource.org/greenhouse/greenhouse/blobs/master/src/main/java/com/springsource/greenhouse/validation/ConfirmValidator.java).